# Select customers without address

Tags: mysql

There are two tables ps_customer and ps_address.

```
ps_customer contains: id_customer and customer.email
ps_address contains: id_customer and few other fields.
```

I want to select customers who's data is not present in ps_address table.
I'm using Sql Query:

```
SELECT id_customer, customer.email FROM ps_customer 
WHERE id_customer NOT IN SELECT id_customer FROM ps_address;
```

But it throws the error that there is something wrong with query `SELECT id_customer FROM ps_address`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put brackets round the last part of your query to indicate that it's a subquery:

```
SELECT id_customer, customer.email FROM ps_customer 
WHERE id_customer NOT IN ( SELECT id_customer FROM ps_address );
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a LEFT OUTER JOIN on those two tables.

```
SELECT PSC.id_customer, PSCcustomer.email
FROM ps_customer PSC
LEFT OUTER JOIN ps_address PSA on PSC.id_customer = PSA.id_customer 
WHERE PSA.id_customer IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use left join for this something as

```
select 
c.id_customer,
c.customer.email 
from ps_customer c
left join ps_address a on a.id_customer = c.id_customer
where a.id_customer is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using left join

```
SELECT id_customer, customer.email FROM ps_customer pc left join ps_address pa
on pc.id_customer = pa.id_customer
where pa.id_customer is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use left join for it:

```
SELECT id_customer, customer.email 
FROM ps_customer 
   left join ps_address on ps_customer.id_customer= ps_address.id_customer 
where ps_address.id_customer is null;
```

or if you want to use subqueries you have to use `()` arround the subquery:

```
SELECT id_customer, customer.email FROM ps_customer 
WHERE id_customer NOT IN ( SELECT id_customer FROM ps_address );
```